# Dropdown select won't work correctly for mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My dropdown works fine on desktop, but not at mobile. If I select one of the options (A,B,C aso.), for mobile it doesn't have any effect to the displayed boxes.

Why? Is a submit button required for mobile?

The script:

```
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('#parent > span').fadeIn(250);
    } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).delay(50).fadeIn(200);
        $('#parent > span').not($el).fadeOut(0);
    }
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z1azqrz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing a `click` handler on `option` elements is not a good idea as it is not widely supported, in fact it didn't work at all in Chrome, let alone a mobile browser and is what's causing your problem.

Instead, hook to the `change` event on the `select` element and read the `id` property from the selected `option`. You need to amend your logic, something like this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var selectedId = $('option:selected', this).prop('id')
    if (selectedId == 'all') {
        $('#parent > span').fadeIn(250);
    } else {
        var $el = $('.' + selectedId).delay(50).fadeIn(200);
        $('#parent > span').not($el).fadeOut(0);
    }
})
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7z1azqrz/2/)

The same applies to trying to style the selected `option` element - leave it to the browser to style as most CSS properties won't work on them.

Comment: Ouh, ok, it makes sense. Thx for support!